# Create a list of lists of lists in a single line

Tags: python, list

This code creates a list of 25 lists of 25 lists:

```
vals = []
for i in range(25):
    vals.append([])
    for j in range(25):
        vals[i].append([])
```

How could I translate this code to a single line instead of using 5 lines in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`list_comprehension`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/).

```
res = [[[] for _ in range(25)] for _ in range(25)]
```

To check that result is the same, we can use [`numpy.ndarray.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.asarray(vals).shape
(25, 25, 0)

>>> np.asarray(res).shape
(25, 25, 0)
```

Comment: Why NumPy instead of simply `res == vals`?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I want to show that both of them same shape. Yes we can use `res == vals`

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension:

```
vals = [[[] for _ in range(25)] for _ in range(25)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` way:

```py
import numpy as np

vals = np.zeros((25,25,0)).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach based on `map`:

```py
vals = list(map(lambda _: list(map(lambda __: [], range(25))), range(25)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a fun hack for lazy people:

```
vals = eval(repr([[[]] * 25] * 25))
```

Comment: What's the issue?